# PHP - How to save the exact time and date when

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, checkbox, time

How can I save, in a database, the exact moment (time and date) when an user "tick" checkboxes?

I have 3 checkboxes to tick before proceeding with registration, and I need to save in the database the time and date when the user tick each checkbox (so 3 different times).

Comment: Yes of course it's possible.

Comment: use 'now()' key word in your database query

Comment: You need to use jquery or javascript to get time of each checkbox especially when they are checked and used some hidden field where you will stored tme you get when checked on checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery, when the checkbox is clicked change the value of that checkbox and submit your form data..

```js
function changeValue(id)
{
 $('#checkbox'+id).val(new Date($.now()));
 $('#span'+id).html('Clicked at '+new Date($.now()));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type ='checkbox'  id="checkbox1" name="a"  onClick="changeValue('1');" >Checkbox 1
<span id="span1"></span><br>
<input type ='checkbox'  id="checkbox2" name="b" onClick="changeValue('2');" >Checkbox 2
<span id="span2"></span><br>
<input type ='checkbox'  id="checkbox3" name="c" onClick="changeValue('3');" >Checkbox 3
<span id="span3"></span>
```

Comment: It worked!

Now how can I send the values to a database?

I can't use the tag inside an input text because I'm on WordPress and I can't use a value like this because of my theme...

Comment: @davideakc yes you can... :) glad to help you..

Comment: Is it possible to send a simple HTML line like <span id="span1"></span> (without put it into an input) to a database?

Comment: @davideakc you do not need to send span, this is for example only, look that part of code `$('#checkbox'+id).val(new Date($.now()));` this will automatically changes the value of your input when you click on checkbox span tag is for showing only that you have cliked

Comment: For this strategy, the listener can be simply `this.value=new Date()`. Less code and hugely more efficient than the jQuery equivalent.

Comment: So for sending it into a database how do I recall the checkboxes?

Like this?

$agreed3=$_POST['agree3']; (where "agree3" is the id of the checkbox)

Comment: you need a submit button to post your data, when you click on button your data will be posted to the action file given in your form.

Comment: I already have a form with fields, button etc...

I use the $_POST variable for recall the input that user types in field but I don't know how to take the value of the checkbox...

Comment: simply with the name of checkbox, for example, if this is your input `<input type ='checkbox' "name="checkbox_name"  >` then you will get the value of  this input like `$val =$_POST['checkbox_name'];`

Comment: Ok, solved!

Many thanks!

Comment: @davideakc why unaccepted my answer ??

Answer (score 0):

The 'now()' keyword save the actual time...

If someone ticks the first box at 11:50AM and the second at 11:51AM, in the database must be inserted both different hour

Comment: For that case, on change of that check box store current time in some hidden field & save them when you save user input.

Answer (score 0):

1. at the time data save use "now()" which is mysql function.
2. you can set database table's column default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing answer because i can't comment. You would need to use a javascript function to populate the value of the checkbox to the current time